# remove special index character from string | flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I want to remove the the 3rd character, If the 3rd character(index) of the String is "0".

for example

```
String a = "850666";
String b = "8526668";
```

I want to get `85666` as "a" and `8526668` as "b"

(Length of Strings are not same)

My try:

```
void checkNumber(String loginToken) {
    if (loginToken[3] == "0") {
      String first = loginToken.substring(0, 2);
      String nd = loginToken.substring(4, loginToken.length - 1);
      String finalone = first + nd;
      showSnackBarGreen(context, finalone, finalone);
    }
  }
```

It does not work perfectly, help me to continue

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceRange.html

Comment: In Dart, string indices begin at 0. So, in your example, `a[0] == '8'`, `a[1] == '5'`, `a[2] == '0'`, and so on. Your code exhibits at least two off-by-one issues relating to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, remember to check if the input length is less than 3 characters. Next, check the value of the 3rd element, then use `String::replaceRange()` to remove it. I've written a function `process` for you as a demo, as well as a few test cases to run it.

```
String process(String input) {
  if (input.length < 3) return input;
  if (input[2] != '0') return input;
  return input.replaceRange(2, 3, '');
}

void main() {
  print(process('12'));
  print(process('120'));
  print(process('123'));
  print(process('1204'));
  print(process('1200'));
  print(process('1200'));
  print(process('12001'));
}
```

Sample output:

> 12 12 123 124 120 120 1201

Answer (score 2):

```
void checkNumber(String loginToken) {
  if (loginToken[2] == "0") {
    String first = loginToken.substring(0, 2);
    String nd = loginToken.substring(first.length+1, loginToken.length);
    String finalone = first + nd;
    showSnackBarGreen(context, finalone, finalone);
  }
}
```